# list in lists with various length vector to dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I created a list of lists (list-list-list) using for loop and I'd like to make a dataframe importing the first value of each list to a first column and second value to a second column and all others for the last column. Finally, I want to extract the data to excel csv file.

For example (expected result):

| Name | Title | Others |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Clean]1 | ALL_2 | x2, Type, Name |
| AP3 | age+ | ID, submission, submission2, abc, gender, submission |

```
> temp_lst3[[1]]

[[1]]

[1] "[Clean]1" "ALL_2" "x2" "Type"                   
[5] "Name"                                     

[[2]]

[1] "AP3" "age+" "ID" "submission" "submission2"
[5] "abc" "gender" "submission"                  

[[3]]

[1] "ID" "Traditional" "call" "number"
[5] "gender" "abc" "gender" "abc"
[9] "number"
```

It's not a clean data, but it would be most appreciated if anyone can help! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(temp_lst3,function(x){
    data.frame(
      "Name"=x[1],
      "Title"=x[2],
      "Others"=paste0(x[3:pmax(3,length(x))],collapse=",")
    )
  })
)

      Name       Title                                          Others
1 [Clean]1       ALL_2                                    x2,Type,Name
2      AP3        age+ ID,submission,submission2,abc,gender,submission
3       ID Traditional        call,number,gender,abc,gender,abc,number
```